# MongoDB - Pull and Update in a single query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following schema -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c3253f19862e6347bc9f4e"),
    "farm_id": "Gustavo-chainer",
    "first_ts" : ISODate("2021-05-18T09:53:00.000Z"),
    "last_ts" : ISODate("2021-05-18T12:53:00.000Z"),
    "sensor_data" : [ 
        {
            "data" : 76.0,
            "sensor": "temperature-sensor",
            "start_ts" : ISODate("2021-05-18T09:33:00.000Z"),
            "end_ts" : ISODate("2021-05-18T09:53:00.000Z")
        },
        {
            "data" : 74.0,
            "sensor": "temperature-sensor",
            "start_ts" : ISODate("2021-05-18T12:33:00.000Z"),
            "end_ts" : ISODate("2021-05-18T12:53:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

where first_ts = minimum of all the values of start_ts present in the sensor_data array and last_ts = maximum of all the values of end_ts present in the sensor_data array.

I want to delete a data point from sensor_data array given the start_ts and end_ts and after deletion, have to **update the first_ts and last_ts accordingly**.

**Example -**

Delete data point with "start_ts" : ISODate("2021-05-18T12:33:00.000Z") and "end_ts" : ISODate("2021-05-18T12:53:00.000Z"). After deletion, the document should look like -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c3253f19862e6347bc9f4e"),
    "first_ts" : ISODate("2021-05-18T09:53:00.000Z"),
    "last_ts" : ISODate("2021-05-18T09:53:00.000Z"),
    "sensor_data" : [ 
        {
            "data" : 76.0,
            "sensor": "temperature-sensor" 
            "start_ts" : ISODate("2021-05-18T09:33:00.000Z"),
            "end_ts" : ISODate("2021-05-18T09:53:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to write a **pymongo** query that can do the above task in a single query.

Comment: Will the deletion process be according to the random index?

Comment: @MuratColyaran I have to perform deletion of the data point present in the sensor_data list that matches the given start_ts and end_ts and once the data point corresponding to that is deleted, need to update the root level keys - firts_ts and last_ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `sensor_data` array, check both fields date condition and `$not` for the opposite condition to exclude matching documents
- `$min` to get minimum `start_ts` date from `sensor_data.start_ts`
- `$max` to get maximum `end_ts` date from `sensor_data.end_ts`

```
collection.update(
  {
    sensor_data: {
      $elemMatch: {
        start_ts: ISODate("2021-05-18T12:33:00.000Z"),
        end_ts: ISODate("2021-05-18T12:53:00.000Z")
      }
    }
  },
  [{
    $set: {
      sensor_data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$sensor_data",
          cond: {
            $not: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$$this.start_ts", ISODate("2021-05-18T12:33:00.000Z")] },
                { $eq: ["$$this.end_ts", ISODate("2021-05-18T12:53:00.000Z")] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      first_ts: { $min: "$sensor_data.start_ts" },
      last_ts: { $max: "$sensor_data.end_ts" }
    }
  }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mpAo8FI39bI)